Windows 10 can't connect on a fresh samba 4 installation
I finished a fresh Samba 4 Active Directory Domain controller installation.
Samba version 4.15.13-Ubuntu / Ubuntu 22.04.3
Win7 and WinXP can join the domain but I could not add a Windows 10 machine.
I tried to debug the connection using:
dcdiag /s:LINUX26.MEDIASYS.LAN /u:MSYS\Administrator /p:xxxx
And I got:

Doing primary tests   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\LINUX26
Starting test: Advertising
......................... LINUX26 passed test Advertising
Starting test: FrsEvent
......................... LINUX26 passed test FrsEvent
Starting test: DFSREvent
......................... LINUX26 passed test DFSREvent
Starting test: SysVolCheck
The SysVol is not ready. This can cause the DC to not advertise itself as a DC for netlogon after dcpromo.
Also trouble with FRS SysVol replication can cause Group Policy problems. Check the FRS event log on this DC.
......................... LINUX26 failed test SysVolCheck

I've tried to reset the SYSVOL on Samba but it didn't work either.
Any recomendation on how to fix this?

Check the endpoint in C:\windows\debug\netsetup.log. Also the output of nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/active-directory-domain-join-troubleshooting-guidance
